# Energy bands motion in an npn transistor

Tags: semiconductor-physics, electronics, electronic-band-theory, electrical-engineering

How do electrons move in an npn transistor along their energy bands, in active mode?

How does the base current originate in this energy diagram?

Comment: If you could draw it or add a video I would appreciate it, I do not understand that topic very well.